# Grails taglib that returns a list

Tags: grails, arraylist, spring-security, taglib

I'm trying to create (my first ever) taglib in grails and I sort of got it down except that I'm trying to return a list/array of strings that has to be displayed in a table but all I'm getting is the first value of the list. Here's what I got:

Taglib:

```
def roles = { attrs, body ->
    def user = User.get(attrs.user)

    if(user) {
        def roles = Role.findAllById(UserRole.findByUser(user).roleId)
        def realRoles = []

        roles.each { role ->
            realRoles.add(role.authority.substring(5))
        }

        out << realRoles
        out << body()
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #007FB2;color: #FFFFFF;">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Roles</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <g:each in="${users}" var="user">
        <tr>
            <td>${user.id}</td>
            <td>${user.firstName}</td>
            <td>${user.surname}</td>
            <td>${user.username}</td>
            <td><g:roles user="${user.id}" /></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="gen-btn btn-red" style="width: 100%;" onclick="confDelete(${user.id}, '${user.firstName}');">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>

</table>
```

What's supposed to happen is when the taglib gets called it's supposed to go get all the roles associated with the user id then take each role's authority property and cut the preceding "ROLE_" off of it. So `ROLE_ADMIN` just becomes `ADMIN` and `ROLE_USER` just becomes `USER`, etc. What I'd ideally like is a list that I can loop through in the gsp but I realise that's alot to ask so if I can just get help getting a comma separated list roles back from my taglib I'd really appreciated it.

To make it more clear, what I'm currently getting back is literally `[ROLE_ADMIN]` regardless of whether the user has more roles than that. What I want is a complete list of roles, e.g. `ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_WHATEVER`.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** Here are my User, Role and UserRole domain classes. I am using Spring security to generate these classes.

User:

```
package fake.package.name

class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    String firstName
    String surname
    Date dateCreated
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
        firstName blank: false
        surname blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }

    String toString(){
        if((firstName)&&(surname))
            firstName+ " " +surname
        else
            username
    }
}
```

Role:

```
package fake.package.name

class Role {

    String authority

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }

    static constraints = {
        authority blank: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

UserRole:

```
package fake.package.name

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class UserRole implements Serializable {

    User user
    Role role

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof UserRole)) {
            return false
        }

        other.user?.id == user?.id &&
                other.role?.id == role?.id
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if (user) builder.append(user.id)
        if (role) builder.append(role.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static UserRole get(long userId, long roleId) {
        find 'from UserRole where user.id=:userId and role.id=:roleId',
                [userId: userId, roleId: roleId]
    }

    static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        UserRole instance = UserRole.findByUserAndRole(user, role)
        if (!instance) {
            return false
        }

        instance.delete(flush: flush)
        true
    }

    static void removeAll(User user) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user=:user', [user: user]
    }

    static void removeAll(Role role) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE role=:role', [role: role]
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['role', 'user']
        version false
    }
}
```

Do note that because this a work project and not a personal one I'm not allowed to edit the code in here. Also, I changed the package names to `fake.package.name`, that's not the actual names of the packages.

Comment: Just a quick answer... please look at **UserRole.findByUser(user).roleId**, there you fetch only the first UserRole ...

Comment: Thanks @susi, I figured it out with your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, where your User<->Role Association comes from (Spring Security Framework?) or if it's coded by yourself. And you gave no examples of your domain-classes.

Let me explain another solution a bit:

If you design your domain-classes somehow like the following:

```
package xyz

class User {

    String name

    static hasMany = [authorities: Role]

    static constraints = {
    }
}

---------------

package xyz

class Role {

    static belongsTo = User

    String name

    static hasMany = [user: User]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

a third table 'user_roles' will be created for saving the many-to-many relation/association

With this configuration, you could shorten your taglib to:

```
def roles = { attrs, body ->
    def user = User.get(attrs.user)

    if(user) {
        def realRoles = []
        user.authorities.each { r ->
            realRoles.add(r.authority.substring(5))
        }
        out << realRoles.join(', ')
        out << body()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work though. Shortening it to that gives the error message `Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:roles>: No such property: roles for class: unipoint.oyg.domain.User`. I am indeed using spring security and I will edit my question to include my user, role and userrole domain code.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think it should be **user.authorities.each** instead of user.roles.each because you have a **getAuthorities()** method in your User-class which return all the associated Roles. (Sorry, I still stuck with Apache-Shiro instead of Spring-Security in my current projects...)

Comment: That actually worked. I dare say, you my friend, might be an actual wizard. I thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to susi I managed to figure this thing out. Here: `def roles = Role.findAllById(UserRole.findByUser(user).roleId)` I only returned the first UserRole so I couldn't possibly bring back more than one Role. This is what my taglib method looks like now. I realize it might not be the most efficient and if someone would like to improve on it feel free.

```
def roles = { attrs, body ->
    def user = User.get(attrs.user)

    if(user) {
        def userRoles = UserRole.findAllByUser(user)
        def roles = []
        def realRoles = []

        userRoles.each { ur ->
            roles.add(Role.findById(ur.roleId))
        }

        roles.each { r ->
            realRoles.add(r.authority.substring(5))
        }

        realRoles = realRoles.join(", ")

        println(realRoles)

        out << realRoles
        out << body()
    }
}
```

Starting after the line `if(user) {`:

- I find all the userRoles associated with the user Id
- Then I loop through the list of userRoles and add each ur to a roles list
- Then I loop through the list of Roles and add the formatted role's authority to the realRoles list
- Lastly I use `realRoles = realRoles.join(", ") to remove the square brackets around each`realRoles` item

Answer (score 0):

the root cause is the line

```
def roles = Role.findAllById(UserRole.findByUser(user).roleId)
```

because the UserRole.findByUser(user) just returnes 1 UserRole, roles is just 1 Role object inside a List, instead of all the User's Role objects.

change it to

```
def roles = Role.findAllByIdInList(UserRole.findAllByUser(user)*.roleId)
```

as you seem to be relatively new to Grails, a quick explanation: you can use dynamic finders (find*) in 2 ways: findBy* and findAllBy*. as the naming of the methods suggest, findBy* returns 1 object or null. findAllBy* returns a collection of objects.

Additionally, you can combine the property-names with operations (in our case "InList") to specify the type of search operation.

In this example we first retrieve a list of UserRole objects, transform this list into a list of role ids (using the spread operator "*.") and with these ids retrieve all Role objects having one of these IDs.

as the UserRole class contains a Role property directly, of course we can directly write

```
def roles = UserRole.findAllByUser(user)*.role
```

keep in mind, that this list could possibly contain null if the property role on UserRole class was nullable (it's not the case here, but if any reader has a similar problem but with a nullable association).

summarized, what you are doing in the taglib at the moment, could be written as:

```
out << UserRole.findAllByUser(user)*.role.collect({ it.substring(5) }).join(', ')
```

and just a little comment to the previous answer from susi:

that code shows a direct many-to-many association between User and Role.

as Burt Beckwith wrote some time ago https://mrpaulwoods.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/implementing-burt-beckwiths-gorm-performance-no-collections/

this can have impact on performance as every new User that gets added to a Role requires hibernate to load all existing User-Role-Connections, which could cause trouble when you have lots of users.

That's why the scaffolded domain classes of spring-security-core (since 2.x version iirc) now explicitely define the UserRole-class.